# Why I can't use "return" in my code at Java?

Tags: java, return

I have a problem with my Java Code at the fourth line.
I have this error: "this method must return a result of type int". 
So I didn't return 'c'. How can I return?

```
public class bese_bolunme {

static int function(int b) 
{

    for (int c=0;c<b;c++) 
    {

        if(c%5==0) 
        {
            System.out.println(c);
            return c;
        }



    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    function(36);
}
```

Comment: Your function *must always* return an integer, at the moment it only does so if b is larger than 5. The compiler can see that you have a conditional in a loop, so it knows there are ways the function could get to the end *without* returning.

Comment: You are missing ultimate return in method . Cause method with return type has to return in every case . Just return default value from end of method .

Comment: How can I change my code?

Comment: We don't know, because we don't know what the logic should be in the case that the condition is never met. There should probably be another return outside the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you declared in your function signature that it returns an Integer, you must, in all execution flows of your function return an Integer.

```
static int function(int b) 
{

   for (int c=0;c<b;c++) 
   {

    if(c%5==0) 
    {
        System.out.println(c);
        return c;
    }
} //end for loop
 return -1;     //Or other logic you prefer
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On every execution path in the method `function(int b)` a `return` statement must be reached. You are taking care of not all paths: I.e. what should the method return in case of not entering the `for` loop?